# c++ custom error-code class or system errno

Tags: c++, error-handling, error-code

We are in the very initial stages of a large project and one of the initial thing to do is to define the error codes b/w the different modules. Previously we used the system errno as error codes and used strerror() to print the error. This is very simple and works fine [most of our earlier code was C may be 10% C++].

In the new project [fully in C++], I am confused if we should just follow that. Or define our own error class.

eg:

```
enum class ErrorCode {

FILE_EXIST = EEXIST,
ACCESS_DENIED = EACCESS,
...
};

const char *error_str (ErrorCode code)
{
    switch (code) {
        case ACCESS_DENIED: return "Access denied";
        ...
    }
}

class Error {
   Error (ErrorCode code) : _code (code){}
   Error() : _code(0){}

   void operator = (ErrorCode code);
   bool operator == (ErrorCode code);
   operator bool() {return _code != 0;}
   const char *string() { return error_str(_code);}

private:
   ErrorCode _code;
};
```

This is just a wrapper class with some C++ sugar. But having defined this, I think it doesn't add any value to the int/strerror() other than a possibility of extension and unnecessarily make things verbose. I guess the above doesnt add too much performance penalty compared to errno as it has only an int within it.

Need advice - in your experience with large c++ projects, how did it go?

Comment: Why not exceptions?

Comment: Exceptions yes.. but in cases where we have to use error codes

Comment: Back then when we were rewriting our C++ server and using APIs returning codes we were converting it to exceptions. For example for Win32 APIs we were using `FormatMessageA` to get the error description and then throwing Win32Exception defined as `class Win32Exception : public std::runtime_error` and the base was initialized with error description retrieved by `FormatMessageA`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/ae60nb/decades_have_passed_standard_c_has_no_agreed_and/

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg please see this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf

Comment: @MGH two years latter it would be rather precious info to learn which path have you taken and what are the experiences. Your solution above is good as any, certainly better than using `<system_error>` or `std::errc` or exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `std::error_code` in `system_error`, seems to do what you want. [This](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html) is a good tutorial on how it works. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760851/stderror-code-my-errorcheck-block-my-errorvalidate-my-erroraccept) post also explains in detail how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Also please see this https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/ae60nb/decades_have_passed_standard_c_has_no_agreed_and/ and the discussion thread bellow it.